# How to solve this system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

```
x ≡ 1 mod 5
x ≡ 4 mod 7
x ≡ 8 mod 5
```

I know the "rule" of posting a tentative of solving before asking for help, but I just don't have what to post here. I tried to apply TCR but don't for this system because I have inconsistent congruences there.

Any ideea please?

Comment: It might be hard to find an $x$ for which $x\equiv 1$ mod $5$ and $x\equiv 8$ mod $5$, don't you think?

Comment: @5xum i'm sure we can if we try *really* hard.

Comment: Seriously though, $$1\not\equiv3\equiv8\pmod{5}$$

Comment: Apply "Chinese remainder theorem" (to the correct version of the problem)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the correct version of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I thought that you just made a typo, but as I see, you recognise that you have incosistent congruences in your problem. That is the key here, I think. The thing is that any $x$ that satisfies the equation $x\equiv 1\mod 5$ is of the form $x=5k + 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. On the other hand, any $x$ that satisfies $x\equiv 8\mod 5$ is of the form $5l+8$ (or $5l+3$, since $8=5+3$) for some $l\in\mathbb Z$.

But for any two $l,k\in\mathbb Z$, you can see that $5k+1$ *cannot* equal $5l + 3$ as that would imply that $$5k+1=5l+3\\ 5(k-l) = 2$$
which would imply (since $k-l\in\mathbb Z$) that $5|2$ which is obviously not true.

Another way of looking it is that $x\equiv 1\mod 5$ implies 
$$x\in\{\dots,-9,-4,1,6,11,16,\dots\}=S_1$$ and $x\equiv 8\mod 5$ implies $$x\in\{\dots,-7,-2,3,8,13,18,\dots\} = S_2.$$

Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ have an empty intersection, this means that $x$ must be an element of two sets which have no common element, therefore, $x$ cannot exist.